Has eye-tracking for UX ever been validated as a research method?
This article: Eyetracking: Is It Worth It? :: UXmatters, reminded of just how much nonsense is abundant in the UX research field. I realized that I had been taking eye-tracking for granted as an established UX research method quite unjustly. I was not able to find any studies validating it as a method, at least, as far as the UX field is concerned.
Let's say we have three variations of a sign-up web UI: one has already been proven as usable through moderated usability testing and usability checklists, while the second one has been proven to be unusable through moderated usability testing again and through intentional valuation of usability principles. The third one has only a small number of things done wrong on purpose and has gone through moderated testing, again, proving it to provide poor, yet not worst usability. Validation requires that eye-tracking research conclusions should convincingly coincide with those from the moderated testing.
Have you ever stumbled upon such studies or got observations from personal experience?

I think the article simply shows that research involves piecing together different types of information in order to arrive at your own conclusion about something.
That there is a sure fire way to prove or disprove something, and that any conclusion is absolute would seem to be counterintuitive to the scientific process and way of thinking.
Eye-tracking data on its own doesn't necessary give you the full picture when it comes to understanding usability. But when combined with other data points, it can point you towards the way users engage or move through the UI.
Unfortunately, eye-tracking data is often used on its own to make stronger conclusions than it should (due to its costs needing to be justified), or doesn't add too much insight to already problematic designs that can easily be picked up via other means. Suffice to say, if eye-tracking is absolutely essential and definitive, it would definitely be in wide-spread usage despite the cost. Yet no single research method is like that, so the most efficient (cost and time-wise) usually wins out in the end.
Having said that, eye-tracking would be very useful for AR/VR applications research, yet I haven't seen much of it there either.

My question was not about the article. I mentioned the article as something which prompted me to question eye-tracking, specifically, whether it has ever been validated or not. Your answer mentions nothing about validation.

@drabsv my answer is not about the article either. No research methodology alone will give you a definitive answer. Combine multiple methods together and you improve the probability of reaching a correct conclusion. The point is that no research method is perfect, but used correctly it will give you the data you need to collect. It doesn't stop people trying to reach incorrect conclusions with the data, but it will happen whether eye-tracking is validated or not. Surveys have always been known to be flawed as well and it is still used, hopefully in combination with other research methods...

there's a huge gap between a method not being perfect and a method not being validated. if a method has been tried to be validated multiple times and has consistently failed we can admit that is provenly bogus. What is the point of combining it with other methods then? It's like telling "fortune telling is not perfect either, but let's include in in our research mix, just in case".

@drabsv the current methods for eye tracking works as intended, but to be able to conclude what someone is thinking or why they are doing something by relying on eye tracking data would be like fortune telling. The only way to paint a holistic picture of what a user is thinking in the context of doing something is to use a combination of qualitative and quantitative research methods. In fact, you'll find that it's usually the cheaper and more cost-effective methods that are used in most research plans, rather than the type of information you need and the most accurate way of obtaining it.
